# Cannot access Atlad MongoDB with NoSQLBooster or MongoDB Compass.>dot net project throws 'Could not load file or assembly'

Tags: asp.net, nosql, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-compass

I am trying to connect to one of the db named 'ZephyrHelp' in a cluster in atlas mongo. Only using Robo3t, i can connect to my cluster and view it but cant do much like export/import of collections.

1. When I try to connect through NoSQLBooster, it throws error "bad auth Authentication failed." but the exact settings can connect through robo3t then why not for Nosqlbooster ?

robo 3t settings:

connection type=>replica set

members:cluster0-shard-00-00-izzjt.mongodb.net:27017

authentication db is set to admin and username and password are provided. auth mechanism is SCRAM-SHA-1.
ssl connection with self signed certiicate

2. i tried to go with mongo compass. now from atlasmongo i got the

connection string :
mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-izzjt.mongodb.net/test
i tried = > mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-izzjt.mongodb.net/ZephyrHelp

but in both the case it threw error "Server selection timed out after 30000 ms".

3. In the project integration part when I'm trying to connect to the db using the connection string provided by them via :

_client = new MongoClient("mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-izzjt.mongodb.net/ZephyrHelp?retryWrites=true&w=majority");

it throws an error "Could not load file or assembly 'DnsClient, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4574bb5573c51424' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Can someone point out if there is any issue with compatibility or anything or is there something I'm doing wrong ?

.net project target framework  4.7.2
dns client is v1.2.0
mongocsharpdriver,mongodb.Bson/Driver/Driver.core are all v2.8.1.